# Questions about DNS, BIND and setup

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind

I have a few questions which I can't find the answer.

- Is it possible to create two nameservers (ns1,ns2) with one IP ?
- To move my server DNS from godaddy to ns1/ns2.my_domain.com, I can use Bind ?
- If I install Bind, create a master zone (www, ns1, ns2, mail, pop, etc.), set it up. Then create second master zone (reverse), set it up. Log into godaddy account and change the nameservers to ns1/ns2.my_domain.com. Is it enough for the redirection to work ?

Here's my named.conf :

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "my_domain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/my_domain.com.hosts";
    };

zone "67.4.70.xxx.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/xxx.70.4.67.rev";
    };
```

Here's the content from /var/named/my_domain.com.hosts

```
$ttl 38400
my_domain.com.  IN  SOA my_domain.com. root.localhost. (
            1364566563
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
my_domain.com.  IN  NS  my_domain.com.
my_domain.com.  IN  A   xxx.70.4.67
www.my_domain.com.  IN  A   xxx.70.4.67
mail.my_domain.com. IN  A   xxx.70.4.67
ns1.my_domain.com.  IN  A   xxx.70.4.67
ns2.my_domain.com.  IN  A   xxx.70.4.67
pop.my_domain.com.  IN  A   xxx.70.4.67
smtp.my_domain.com. IN  A   xxx.70.4.67
my_domain.com.  IN  NS  ns1.my_domain.com.
my_domain.com.  IN  NS  ns2.my_domain.com.
my_domain.com.  IN  MX  10 mail.my_domain.com.
```

Here's the content from /var/named/xxx.70.4.67.rev

```
$ttl 38400
67.4.70.xxx.in-addr.arpa.   IN  SOA my_domain.com. root.locahost. (
            1364575048
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
67.4.70.xxx.in-addr.arpa.   IN  NS  my_domain.com.
67.4.70.xxx.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR my_domain.com.
```

Any help would be really appreciated ^^

Thanks.

Comment: It's a _really bad idea_ to put two nameservers on the same address. The point of having multiple NS is to create redundant copies of the zone on separate machines. What is the "redirection" you mention?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem is I only have one IP, maybe 2 more IPs that are shared but I'm not sure. By "redirection" I meant is this setup enough for the domain name to be associated to my IP ?

Comment: If you can't host two DNS servers on two completely separate servers on separate networks, you're better off leaving it where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Is it possible to create two nameservers (ns1,ns2) with one IP ?

Don't do that.

If you don't have another machine to use as a secondary NS, use one of the multitude of free services out there that will do this for you.

> - To move my server DNS from godaddy to ns1/ns2.my_domain.com, I can use Bind ?

Yes.

> - If I install Bind, create a master zone (www, ns1, ns2, mail, pop, etc.), set it up. Then create second master zone (reverse), set it up. Log into godaddy account and change the nameservers to ns1/ns2.my_domain.com. Is it enough for the redirection to work ?

For the forward zone: Yes. It is unlikely that they will delegate the reverse zone to you.

Note that if you're going to have your NS hostnames inside your zone, you will need to add glue records via your domain registrar. This is essentially a "bootstrap" for other name servers to be able to resolve your NS addresses.